# Give the option to always choose a browser to open a link

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a way to let the user always choose which application (browser) that should open a specific link? Similar to what happens if the user hasn't chosen the default program yet.

My code

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            forumintent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following method works for all implicit intents - not limited to your question about browsers.

Generally. when you issue an implicit intent (like `ACTION_VIEW`), the host Android device will check to see whether there is a default app to handle the intent. If there is a default app, then, by default, android will automatically redirect to the app.

However, you can force an app chooser for implicit intents. For this, you need to use `Intent.createChooser()` method. See this example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // only used based on your example.

String title = "Select a browser";
// Create intent to show the chooser dialog
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);

// Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Comment: The solution that @Kasra proposes is correct. You have to clear the default browser setting at your device in order to show always the browser app chooser. That's the way that worked for me.