# How to show a Yes/No alert dialogue before opening a link from webview app to mobile browser?

Tags: android, webview, android-alertdialog

I have an webview android application. In which all link except my site url automatically open into mobile browser (without showing any alert or browser choosing option). Now I want to show a Yes/No alert button before opening the link into mobile browser.

I used the code below to pass all external link from my webview app to mobile browser.

```
if (!url.contains("my site url")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

I asked a detail question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730791/webview-app-how-to-download-a-file-inside-webview-app-external-link-should-op). But didn't get any solution. That's why I'm asking related question.

Answer (score 0):

simply instantiate the alertdialog.show() in the else clause, which will open dialog for every url other than your own url in the if condition.

Comment: What will be the final code, could you tell me? Here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730791/webview-app-how-to-download-a-file-inside-webview-app-external-link-should-op) is my full code.