# “Unfortunately, … has stopped” when Downloading file from Android Webview app in certain device

Tags: android, crash, android-webview, android-download-manager

In my android Web view app I used code below to download file from app. It's working well  and I can download file on my Samsung J2 (Android 5.2.2. API 22) ( but when I'm trying download any file from Symphony i10 ( Android 6. API 23) it “Unfortunately, … has stopped”. I didn't try with any other device. But I tried from Android Emulator ( virtual device API 24 and API 26). Same problem showing.

How can I solve this problem?

Main Activity:

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            boolean value = true;
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
            if (extension != null) {
                MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                String mimeType = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                if (mimeType != null) {
                    if (mimeType.toLowerCase().contains("pdf")                                                           

                            || extension.toLowerCase().contains("jpeg")
                            || extension.toLowerCase().contains("jpg")
                            || extension.toLowerCase().contains("png")                        



                            ) {
                        DownloadManager mdDownloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                                Uri.parse(url));
                        String name= URLUtil.guessFileName(url,null,MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
                        File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),name);
                        request.setDescription("Downloading...");
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        // request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,name);
                        mdDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
                        //value = false;
                    }
                }


                if (!url.contains("my site url")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // only used based on your example.
                    String title = "Select a browser";
                    // Create intent to show the chooser dialog
                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                    // Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
                    // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(chooser);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;

        }


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)  {
            wv.loadUrl(mypage_error);
        }
    });
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />      
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
```

gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName '3.5'
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

SDK

[image]

Note that [my previous question is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730791/webview-app-how-to-download-a-file-inside-webview-app-external-link-should-op) like this: files will download mentioned above (extension) and except my site url all link should open mobile browser. Bu I didn't get answer that's why I used code below to warn before opening external link.

```
if (!url.contains("my site url")) { // Could be cleverer and use a regex

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // only used based on your example.
                    String title = "Select a browser";
                    // Create intent to show the chooser dialog
                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
                    // Verify the original intent will resolve to at least one activity
                    // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivity(chooser);
                    }

                    return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add Requesting Permissions at Run Time API 23+

Ref link:~

[https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

Or Ref.link:~

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/